# How to access response from boto3 bucket.put_object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, httpresponse, put

Looking at the boto3 docs, I see that [`client.put_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) has a `response` shown, but I don't see a way to get the response from [`bucket.put_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket).

**Sample snippet:**

```
        s3 = boto3.resource(
                's3',
                aws_access_key_id=redacted,
                aws_secret_access_key=redacted,
        )

        s3.Bucket(bucketName).put_object(Key="bucket-path/" + fileName, Body=blob, ContentMD5=md5Checksum)

        logging.info("Uploaded to S3 successfully")
```

How is this accomplished?

Comment: The response information is all captured in `S3.Object`.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I read `S3.Object`?

Answer (score 2):

[put_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.put_object) returns [S3.Object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object), which in turn has the [wait_until_exists](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.wait_until_exists) method.

Therefore, something along these lines should be sufficient (my verification code is bellow):

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

with open('test.img', 'rb') as f:

    obj = s3.Bucket('test-ssss4444').put_object(
            Key='fileName', 
            Body=f)
    
obj.wait_until_exists() # optional

print("Uploaded to S3 successfully")
```

`put_object` is a **blocking operation**. Thus it will block your program until your file is uploaded. Therefore `wait_until_exists` is not really needed. But if you want to make sure that the upload actually went through and the object is in S3 you can use it.

Comment: This is great information thank you. But how do I view the HTTP *response* from the `put_object`? I'm looking for things like `ETag`, `MD5`, `Status 200`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `boto3.client` instead of `boto3.resource` to get the response information like ETag and etc. It has a little bit different syntax.

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.put_object(Bucket='bucket-name', Key='fileName', Body=body)
```